# PHP Feedback For Undisplayed Data

Tags: php, mysql

I show the countries as is_country=1. When is_country=2, that country will not be displayed. Let's say all columns is_country=2 then how can I return the text "no such country" in my index page?

I hope I was able to explain.

`country`table

```
|id    | country   | is_country|  
|------| ------    | --------  |
|1     | Londra    |    1      | 
|2     | Manchester|    1      |
|3     | New York  |    2      |
```

My php code is below.

```
$date= $connect->prepare(SELECT * From country
WHERE  is_country='1' ";

$date->execute(array());
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `then how can I return the text "no such country" in my index page?` By checking the number of rows you get back from the database

Comment: @Baracuda078 I didn't quite understand when you said "by checking the number of rows you retrieved from the database", could you write it as code?

Comment: Assuming your index page is a PHP file you should be able to access the is_country values. Then with a if-statement you could check if it is or isn't a country and display it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
$date= $connect->prepare("SELECT * From country WHERE is_country='1')";
if ($date->rowCount() == 0) {
    echo "No country found";
}
```